Electrostatic shielding seems to contradict Gauss's law
Let's assume we have an non-conducting sphere of charge $Q$ and radius $R$. If we choose as a gaussian surface a hollow sphere with the same center and radius $r>R$, it's easy to show using symmetry arguments that the electric field made by the sphere in the radius $r$ is $\frac{kQ}{r^2}$, like a point charge. Now we put the sphere in the center of an uncharged conducting sphere with radius $R'>R$. Due to electrostatic shielding, the field at $r>R'>R$ becomes $0$.1 But if we choose the same gaussian surface, the enclosed charge remains the same (because the conducting sphere is neutral) and the symmetry remains the same - therefore the field at $r$ should remain the same.
How can this apparent contradiction be solved?


The Feynman Lectures on Physics, Vol II, Lecture 5 - Application of Gauss’ Law:


The same arguments can be used to show that no static distribution of charges inside a closed grounded conductor can produce any fields outside.


The grounding simply induces charge $-Q$ on the exterior sphere. There is no contradiction.

Oh, so actually the conductor is not neutral?

Note that Feynman is talking about a grounded conductor as the shield. When you ground the conductor charge can flow on or off the conductor through the connection to ground. The shield will acquire a charge equal and opposite to the charge inside it. If the shield is not grounded then it remains neutral and now the field outside it is not zero.

Yes. Nobody said that grounded stuff have to be exactly neutral.

I understand. Thank you all!

Feynman gives there a proof for the opposite case - there is no electric field in the cavity if there is no charge inside. Does it depend on grounding as well? He doesn't seem to mention it there.
